# How to pass in an array from a script to main(args[])

Tags: java, arrays, bash, shell

I am writing a script that grabs some input from the user. Right now I am have 3 varaibles: 2 strings and one array. I am able to pass in my 2 strings just fine to main, but I do not know how to pass in the array along with the rest.

This is what I have right now

```
java $myJava $var1 $var2 $array
```

Java's main accepts only an array of String, so var1 and var2 work just fine, but how can I pass in my array, which consists of variable number of inputs from the user? Is there a way that I can convert my array to numerous variables and then pass it into main?

Comment: Java's main accepts varargs as well. `main(String... args)`.

Comment: every argument after `var2` is the array simple... just copy to another array

Comment: @Gendarme, well yes, but how does that address the OP's question?  Spelling the `main()` method's signature with varargs syntax doesn't actually change the interface it presents.

Comment: @JohnBollinger I am not sure what the OP is asking, but since he mentioned *"variable number of inputs"* I thought varargs could be of help.

Comment: @Gendarme Equally so, OP can just use whatever iteration method is applicable. The length of `args[]` is not fixed.

Comment: main accepts only String array and hence you cannot pass an array as a variable.  you need to deconstruct your array to strings to call the main method.

Comment: Is there a way that I can deconstruct my array into a number of separate variables, in my script, and pass that into main?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If `$array` is an actual Bash array (e.g. it was declared using `declare -a array`, or another Bash array creation technique) then you just want to do

```
java $myJava "$var1" "$var2" "${array[@]}"
```

That will extract the array into multiple positional arguments, so that the `args` array that is passed into your `main` will be

```
{ var1 , var2 ,  array[0] , array[1] , array[2] , ... }
```